# Find list of strings between 2 substring combinations in Python

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string variable containing the HTML of an email.
The email contains Google drive attachments(links)

I extract the attachment ID of the same and the Google drive attachments are always in the following format:
`'https://drive.google.com/file/d/123456789/view?/usp=drive_web'`

123456789 being the file ID which I am trying to extract

When there is only one attachment, I extract the ID using the below code:

`html_string.split('<a href "https://drive.google.com/file/d/')[-1].split('/')[0]`

However, I do not know how to extrapolate this where there are multiple file IDs in the HTML string.
I am looking to find a list of all the strings between
this substring - `'<a href "https://drive.google.com/file/d/'`
and the next immideate `'/'`

example:
a small sample HTML file looking like so:
`<a href ='https://drive.google.com/file/d/123456789/view?/usp=drive_web' >attachment_1</a>random HTML text with multiple '/'<a href ='https://drive.google.com/file/d/987654321/view?/usp=drive_web' >attachment_2</a>`

Need to extract the following list :
['123456789','987654321']

Using a code that would work for any number of attachments

Comment: What do you get when you leave the `[-1]` off of the result from `html_string.split`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regular expressions.

```py
import re

re.findall(r'(?<=d\/)\d+', html_sample)
```

where `html_sample` is your text.

This will return a list containing matches of numbers that appear after d/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for regular expression. You can use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to write and test your expression. Can't tell you exect syntax for python, you'd need to google that. But you could extract all the matches of google drive urls first to avoid not wanted numbers, then for each url extract numbers using another regex. You could do the same with simple find and replace as well, actually, but that would take more of code for that.
Combined regex with [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function can be simple and short code.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix your `html_string.split` call, you'll find it is returning a list whose elements (except for the first) each start with one of the numbers you want.